# Enabling or Compiling PHP with mcrypt?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mcrypt

phpMyAdmin states that the mcrypt extension is missing. I do have `php_mcrypt.dll` (in the ext folder) and also `libmcrypt.dll` (in the PHP root folder), and I did enable

```
extension=php_mcrypt.dll
```

in the php.ini file, though phpMyAdmin is still stating that it is missing it.

Now I am wondering, is it enabled or still not enabled? The [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.installation.php) states that you have to compile PHP with mcrypt, how exactly is that done?

I did download libmcrypt-2.5.8 but I do not see any files I could install.

Comment: You've omitted two important bits of info: your PHP version and how you installed it in the first place (*.msi installer, ZIP package, compiled from source...).

Comment: Sorry about that one, I did not even notice. My PHP version is 5.3.8 and I did choose the msi installation, I also just had a look and in this version the mcrypt extension is not included in the installation options.

Answer (score 1):

In the PHP/5.3.8 binaries included in the *.MSI installer you should already have the Mcrypt extension since it bundles a static version of the extension that you cannot even remove (since there's no separate DLL). If you have a `php_mcrypt.dll` file in your `ext` directory, a `libmcrypt.dll` file in your PHP root and a `extension=php_mcrypt.dll` line in your `php.ini` file, it's possibly a remaining from some other older version.

In the `phpinfo()` output you should have the following info:

> Build Date: Aug 23 2011 11:47:20
> Compiler: MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008)
>   Architecture: x86
>
> Configure Command
> cscript /nologo configure.js
>   "--enable-snapshot-build" "--disable-isapi" "--enable-debug-pack"
>   "--disable-isapi" "--without-mssql" "--without-pdo-mssql"
>   "--without-pi3web"
>   "--with-pdo-oci=D:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared"
>   "--with-oci8=D:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared"
>   "--with-oci8-11g=D:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient11\sdk,shared"
>   "--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-dotnet"
>   **"--with-mcrypt=static"** "--disable-static-analyze"
>
> Registered Stream Filters
> convert.iconv.*, **mcrypt.***, mdecrypt.*,
>   string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags,
>   convert.*, consumed, dechunk, zlib.*

... as well as a full table titled **mycrypt**.

My advice is to backup your settings, uninstall PHP from Control Panel, remove what's left in the PHP directory and perform a clean install.

Comment: I did do already a clean install and not an over-install. And yes, I do have the file php_mcrypt.dll and the file libmcrypt.dll, I also enabled the extension in the php.ini file. So judging by your post it should already work? Though I do not have anything stating about mcrypt in the phpinfo page.

I also looked in the current msi installation and the extension is not even available for choice.

I am not sure if a whole re-install is going to help.

Comment: Weird... I installed from `php-5.3.8-Win32-VC9-x86.msi` in my own computer and mcrypt is definitively static here (i.e., no DLL). Can you post at least your "Build Date" and "Configure Command" from `phpinfo()`?

Comment: I installed XAMPP instead, I could not get the separate installation to work, thanks for all the help though. I may try the separate installation some time later again.

Comment: @Carpet - I tend to find XAMPP more difficult since you have to edit text files for everything and there're always several copies of the files, but if it works for you it's just fine. However, I'm still curious about your original setup. Too bad we never managed to see the requested info.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://www.landpro.com.au/Windows_7_Install_mcrypt_extension_and_libmcrypt_dll_for_PHP.php

Comment: PHP 5.3 does not contain mcrypt as an available extension anymore as far as I can tell, because I just had a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the library is installed/enabled by checking the output of phpinfo function

Create a file called phpinfo.php add following content.

```
<?php

echo phpinfo();

?>
```

Check the output from browser.

To compile the php with mcrypt support, you have to pass option `--with-mcrypt` (not sure this is correct, but you can find out by issuing `./configure --help` command) while installing php from source.

Then restart your apache server.

### Confirm now by checking output of phpinfo.

UPDATE:

I have no real experience with php in windows. Please try this [link](https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild).

Cheers

Comment: And my question is how exactly is it done, I am not really a command line crack, I do find tutorials but mostly for Linux, how can I achieve the same in Windows with the command prompt? I do know how to install certain files but I do not know how to "compile".